# "So shouldn't you"?

Tags: grammaticality, negation, should

*So shouldn't you*: is this grammatically correct? Or is *you shouldn't either* the only appropriate response?

Comment: Unless you're a very confident (and snarky) speaker of English, go with "*You shouldn't either*".

Comment: Or "neither should you".

Answer (score 1):

These are grammatically correct:

> "He shouldn't do that, and **neither should you**."
>
> "He shouldn't do that, and **you shouldn't either**."

For an affirmative addition to an affirmative remark, use "so" - "He should wait for them and **so should I**".

For a negative addition to a negative remark, use "neither" - "He shouldn't say that, and **neither should you**".

Comment: For the sake of completeness: "*Your brother studies his textbooks for four hours every evening, and was just announced valedictorian of his class.  **So, shouldn't you?***".